# Closing HttpContext.Request.Stream

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following code in my Asp.NET Core 1.1 program:

```
public void UploadMap(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Use(UploadHandler);
}

private async Task UploadHandler(HttpContext httpContext, Func<Task> next)
{
    // Use httpContext.Request.Body to read a file
}
```

Do I need to close the body stream or is this done for me automatically? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_Body) doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have to close the body stream. Just write anything you want to it and the server will serve the bytes for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to end response stream inside middle ware, just do not call `next` (which is basically next middleware)

Comment: Do I need to close the stream _if there is no next middleware_?